# How to lookup Calculation Matrix without Calculation Procedure

Tags: apex, omnistudio, vlocity

How can i lookup data from a Calculation Matrix without making a Calculation Procedure?

I have already tried using this Apex class called: `vlocity_cmt.DefaultPricingMatrixLookupImplementation`. The challenge is i don't know what input/options it need.

The reason i want to do this, is that making a Calculation Procedure pure for calling one matrix seems a bit of lost effort, as it adds zero value.

Yes you can just query the matrix rows and do everything manually. But is there a more efficient method? Preferably provided in the managed package.